# Using Separate Libs for Debug and Release in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I'm downloading GLFW for use with Visual Studio 2010. I see that the download has a separate folder for Debug and Release builds (each folder has two Libs and one DLL), but the filenames in both folders are the same. How should I configure Visual Studio to pick the right file, since I would expect that renaming a Lib or DLL would interfere. My research has been relatively unfruitful, and I *think* it may have to do with `ifdef` commands or something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio build properties (including the directories where it searches for files) are all build configuration specific. On the project configuration dialog, just press the drop-down to switch from Debug to Release. The settings you change will affect that particular build configuration and no others.

If you don't have this dropdown, then you're using the non-advanced interface, which no human being should ever use. Switch to the advanced interface.

Comment: Would it be OK to rename the release DLL and Lib to something different than the debug DLL and Lib so that I can differentiate between them?

Comment: No. You can change the .lib's name, but the .lib stores the name of the .dll that it links to, so if you change the .dll's name, it won't be able to find it.

Comment: OK, so I'll just rename the Lib, and keep track of which DLL is which. Thanks!